# why is the second derivative written as $\frac {d^2 f}{dx^2}$ rather than $\frac {d^2f}{d^2x}$?

Tags: calculus, notation

Is there a good reason for this, or is it just a historical accident?

Comment: See [Second derivative : notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative#Notation) : basically, a convention.

Comment: Loosely speaking it is the change in the change in $f$, divided by the change in $x$ squared (not the change in the change in $x$). This makes sense in view of limits like $\frac{d^2 f}{dx^2}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-(f(x)-f(x-h))}{h^2}$. But ultimately it is convention.

Comment: It is a convention, but also you can think of differentiation as an operator $D$ of ${d \over dx}$, so applying twice would be $D^2$ or ${d^2 \over dx^2}$.

Comment: It works better for more abstract settings. If you view it as an operator, the second derivative operator is the square of first derivative operator. Your suggested notation doesn't really match that quite as well as the convention.

Answer (score 6):

With the current convention for writing derivatives, the differential operator (the symbol that says "differentiate whatever comes after me") is written as $\frac{d}{dx}$. When we take the second derivative we apply that a second time: $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d}{dx}$. On the top, we have two $d$'s, while on the bottom we have two $dx$'s.

We often like to pretend that the $d$, the $dx$ and the fraction line are separate symbols that may be manipulated the way symbols commonly are in algebra. So using the "regular rules" for manipulating fractions, the second derivative operator becomes $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$.

If you don't like operators, then the second derivative of $f$ is given by
$$
\frac{d\frac{df}{dx}}{dx}
$$
i.e. the derivative of the derivative. And, again by applying regular algebraic manipulation rules to this as though they were really fractions, we get $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Notational convention. We write $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d}{dx}= \frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ so the differential operator agrees with the intuition from basic algebra about powers and repeated symbols. If we wrote $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d}{dx}= \frac{d^2}{d^2x}$ it wouldn't agree as well.

Answer (score 1):

The first derivative is denoted by $$\frac {d}{dx}f$$

The derivative of the above is $$\frac {d}{dx}(\frac {d}{dx}f)$$ which is simplified to $$\frac {d^2f}{dx ^2}$$

Note that $(dx)(dx)=(dx)^2 $ is written as $dx^2$  which may seems confusing to some students.

Comment: This doesn’t explain the notation; it just regurgitates it.